# Job scheduler not execute in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[code of oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awNzn.png) I have created a job scheduler with inserting ID an sysdate in table but when i run select * from table; then no records found.

```
create or replace procedure job_schedule_demo_proc is
x number:=1;
y number;
begin
select max(id) into y from job_schedule_demo;
if ( y is null) then
insert into job_schedule_demo values (1,sysdate);
else
x:=y+1;
insert into job_schedule_demo values (x,sysdate);
end if;
commit;
end; 

BEGIN 
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ( job_name=> 'test_full_job_definition',
                                  job_type=> 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                  job_action=> 'BEGIN job_schedule_demo_proc(); END;',
                                  start_date=> SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                  repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; byminute=1; bysecond=0;',
                                  end_date=> NULL,
                                  enabled=> TRUE,
                                  comments=> 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
END;
```

Comment: Shubham, Please update the `job_type = 'STORED_PROCEDURE'` instead of `job_type=> 'PLSQL_BLOCK'` and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai when change job type  = 'STORED_PROCEDURE' then gives error.  but when I run manually scheduler then records inserted successfully into the table.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: 13:17:20  line 1: ORA-27452: BEGIN job_schedule_demo_proc(); END; is an invalid name for a database object.

Comment: done bro . Now automatically inserted records in table  but i want one minute time interval?

Comment: add this repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=60' or FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1; any one of them will work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try manually running the procedure ?

Check this view for additional details regarding status of job run, you will get some clue.

"DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS"

Comment: execute dbms_scheduler.run_job('TEST_FULL_JOB_DEFINITION');
when I execute manually job scheduler then records inserted in table

Comment: what about DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS view ?

Comment: I run manually scheduler then entry goes into that view "DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS"

Comment: then it is issue with scheduling, try changing repeat_interval  like this -  repeat_interval      => 'SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE',

Comment: gives error bcoz single quote issue is there like
 'SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE'
IN '1' then at the start there is single quote and at the start also single quote then gives error like quote not matched

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace job_action with job_action=>  'job_schedule_demo_proc;'. Job_type should remain as same PLSQL_BLOCK

Comment: 13:17:20 line 1: ORA-27452: BEGIN job_schedule_demo_proc(); END; is an invalid name for a database object

above error when i changed plsql_block to STORED_PROCEDURE

Comment: now executed but records not inserted automatically in table

Comment: Remove begin and end because thats making it a pl/sql just replace it with job_action=>  'job_schedule_demo_proc;' I guess job_type can be Pl/sql block as well as the job itself creates it while calling any other procedure etc Ill update my answer

Comment: now executed but  records not inserted automatically in table

Comment: done bro now automatically inserted records in table but I want interval time as one minute then how to do?

Comment: I guess you got the answer now